# How to get Session or EntityManager bound to thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, session, jpa

As I understand when I use hibernate with Spring transactions, a session is bound to thread using ThreadLocal. My questions are:

1. How can I access the session or session factory (without injecting it to the bean) (thus by thread locale)?

   2.How can I do the same in terms of JPA, thus using EnityManager / EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this in a Java EE environment/servlet container?

Comment: No, I try to make it generic (but primarily spring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should use the [SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29) to get your Session. What the session returned from this method depends on the  configuration parameter `hibernate.current_session_context_class` in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`  . If it is set to `thread` ,  the returned session is get from the `ThreadLocal` , which means that if it is called for the first time in the current Java thread, a new Session is opened and returned . If it is called again in the same thread , the same session will be returned.
2. AFAIK , there are no equivalent `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in JPA . I think you have manually  set and get the `EntityManager` to the `ThreadLocal`

---

**Reference**

- [Hibernate Contextual sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session)
- [Sessions and transactions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#Implementing_data_access_objects_DAOs)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out today and ended up doing it this way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpaSessionFactoryName")
private EntityManager jpaSession;
```

I found this documentation very helpful:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa-straight

When you use @PersistenceContext, Spring injects a proxy that gives you an EntityManager bound to the current transaction (or a new one, if there is not any). This looks like a direct substitute for hibernate's:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Although I asked this long time ago, the question explicitly states that I don't want to use injection. Of course spring provides nice facilities that you mentioned. But it did not suit for our use case as I remember.